# Fetch data from webpage in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am learning Selenium and I have a trouble in solving this issue. I have to store all the game bettings in the below link https://www.oddset.de/de/annahmestelle/wettprogramm-kompakt to an array.

I do not have much idea about HTML and Javascript. How can I get Spiel-Nr plus field of all the game bettings to store in to a array.

```
<div id="overview-3" class="accordion level-1"> 
  <div class="accordion-group"> 
    <div class="accordion-heading relative"> 
      <div id="overview-1-3" class="accordion-body in collapse"> 
        <div id="cont_3" class="accordion-inner"> 
          <div class="slv-prog-header"> 
            <div class="left-wrapper"> 
              <div class="middle-wrapper"> 
                <div class="right-wrapper"> 
                  <div class="slv-h slv-t4"> 
                    <div class="slv-h slv-t4"> 
                      <div class="slv-h slv-t5"> 
                        <div class="slv-h slv-t6"> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="slv-h slv-t7"> 
                          <span class="head">Spiel-Nr. PLUS</span
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: would be better to paste the html as an example rather than giving a link to the website.  I, for one, cannot read anything on the linked site due to it being in....german?

Comment: do not ever paste code into a comment.  edit it into your answer.

Comment: Yes its German..The HTML code is too big. I just want all the numbers under the "Spiel-Nr. PLUS" which is in the right most corner of the page. Is it possible to use firebug tool to see the HTML and guide me on this?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can give that column elements ID's so it's easier to get the value

Comment: There is no Column element's ID and the data is displayed in various segments..how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get a List of the correct WebElements:

```
List<WebElement> nrPlusElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".goToEventPage em:nth-of-type(2)"));
```

then:

```
List<String> nrPlusStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement nrPlusElem : nrPlusElements)
{
    nrPlusStrings.add(nrPlusElem.getText());
}
```

to an array:

```
String[] array = nrPlusStrings.toArray(new String[nrPlusStrings.size()]);
```

Mapping them to the correct game might be a little more difficult, but that wasn't the question that was asked.

Comment: How did u find tat? Can you explain a bit? Because I need to find list of elements in other webpage as well.

Comment: I used a Chrome extension called SelectorGadget to narrow down the css selector to the point that all of the value elements were selected.  That, and knowledge of CSS selectors and how they work, which is a whole additional topic.

Comment: I am not getting that.. For example, how to get the fields "SPIEL" marked with "E" in this page https://www.oddset.de/de/annahmestelle/wettprogramm-plus

Comment: use xpath this time:  "//*[contains(@class, 'slv-t3')]//*[contains(@class, 'ellipsis')]//i[contains(@class, 'leftT')]/.."

Comment: Thank you very much..Can you suggest me some links to learn more about xpath and css selector

Comment: https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors for css selectors, and http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf for both.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an XPath like this, which demonstrates how to use 'contains' and 'starts-with' on XPath:

```
String xpathText = 
 ".//div[starts-with(@id,'overview') and contains(@class,'accordion')]//*[@class='head']";
By locator = By.xpath(xpathText);
List<WebElement> nrPlusElements = driver.findElements(locator);
```